# Daunting series of integrals: $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\sin x)^{n-2}}{(1+\sin x)^{n+2}}}\log(\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x})dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

My coleague showed me the following integral yesterday

> \begin{equation}
> I=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\sin x)^{n-2}}{(1+\sin x)^{n+2}}}\log\left(\!\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}\!\right)\ dx=\frac{5}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{3}\tag1
> \end{equation}

He also claimed the following closed-form:

> \begin{equation}
> J=\int_{2}^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\sin x)^{y-2}}{(1+\sin x)^{y+2}}}\log\left(\!\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}\!\right)\ dx\ dy=-\frac{4}{3}\tag2
> \end{equation}

$(1)$ and $(2)$ seem difficult to deal with, but I believe there are some tricks that I can use but I'm not able to spot it yet. Using substitution $x\mapsto\frac\pi2-x$, one gets
\begin{equation}
I=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\cos x)^{n-2}}{(1+\cos x)^{n+2}}}\log\left(\!\frac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x}\!\right)\ dx\tag3
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
J=\int_{2}^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\cos x)^{y-2}}{(1+\cos x)^{y+2}}}\log\left(\!\frac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x}\!\right)\ dx\ dy\tag4
\end{equation}
but I don't know how to use $(3)$ and $(4)$ to evaluate $(1)$ and $(2)$. I'm quite sure that the main problem here is to evaluate
\begin{equation}
K=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\sin x)^{n-2}}{(1+\sin x)^{n+2}}}\log\left(\!\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}\!\right)\ dx
\end{equation}
How does one prove $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Comment: Have you already tried to set $\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}=u$ then deal with the logarithm through differentiation under the integral sign?

Comment: Concerning $(1)$ it seems that if you first sum the series then you get an integral which you can handle with derivatives of the Euler beta function.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I did, but the different power in the square root make it difficult

Comment: @OlivierOloa I'm not so sure with that.

Comment: @SophieAgnesi Did you try the Tangent half-angle substitution?

Comment: @MarcoCantarini It'd be a hell of a lot of works

Comment: @SophieAgnesi We have $K\leq0$.

Comment: $$u=\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}\,\,\,\Rightarrow \quad du=\frac{-2\cos x}{{{(1+\sin x)}^{2}}}dx$$
$$\frac{1}{2\cos x}=\frac{1+u}{4\sqrt{u}}$$

Comment: $$I=\frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty }\int_{0}^{1}\left(u^{\frac{n-3}{2}}+u^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right)\ln{u}\,du$$

Comment: @SophieAgnesi Not really.

Comment: @SophieAgnesi Can you please check the value of $J$? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint**.

1. One may evaluate $(1)$ with the following steps.  From the geometric
   series evaluation $$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\sin
   x)^{n-2}}{(1+\sin x)^{n+2}}}=\frac{1}{(1+\sin
   x)^2}\frac1{1-\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}}},\quad
   0<x<\frac{\pi}2, $$ one may write $$
   I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{(1+\sin x)^2}\frac1{1-\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin
   x}{1+\sin x}}}\log\left( \frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}\right)dx. $$ By
   the change of variable $u=\frac{1-\tan (x/2)}{1+\tan (x/2)}$ we
   obtain a standard integral:

   > $$ I=\int_0^1\frac{1+u^2}{1-u}\:\log u \:du=\frac{5}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{3}. $$
2. One may evaluate $(2)$ by first integrating with respect to $y$ : 
   $$
       J=\int_{2}^{\infty}\!\sqrt{\frac{(1-\sin
       x)^{y-2}}{(1+\sin x)^{y+2}}} dy=-\frac2{(1+\sin x)^2\log\left( \frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x}\right)},\quad
   0<x<\frac{\pi}2,$$ then integrating with respect to
   $x$ one gets a standard integral: $$
   J=\int_{2}^{\infty}\!\!\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\sin
       x)^{y-2}}{(1+\sin x)^{y+2}}}\log\left(\!\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin
       x}\!\right)\ dx\ dy=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2\:dx}{(1+\sin x)^2} $$ which gives

   > $$ J=-\frac43. $$

Comment: Let me check your answer later. (+1)

Comment: You turned out to be correct that $J=-4/3$. Merci beaucoup Olivier.

Comment: De rien, @SophieAgnesi.

Answer (score 19):

Let's employ the *weirdo* substitution taught by my brother: $\sin x=\tanh t$. Doing so, one will get
\begin{align}
K&=\int_0^{\infty}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\tanh t)^{n-2}}{(1+\tanh t)^{n+2}}}\ln\left(\frac{1-\tanh t}{1+\tanh t}\right)\ \frac{dt}{\cosh t}\\[10pt]
&=\int_0^{\infty}\sqrt{\left(\frac{\cosh t-\sinh t}{\cosh t+\sinh t}\right)^{n-2}}\frac{\cosh t}{(\cosh t+\sinh t)^2}\ \ln\left(\frac{\cosh t-\sinh t}{\cosh t+\sinh t}\right)\ dt\\[10pt]
&=-\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(n-2)t}\left(e^{-t}+e^{-3t}\right)\ t\ dt\\[10pt]
&=-\frac{1}{n^2+1}-\frac{1}{n^2-1}
\end{align}
Thus, evaluating $I$ and $J$ are  *easy-peasy-lemon-squeezy*.

Comment: This is a great answer. It shows a new-ish way of thinking, explains it concisely, and is easy to follow.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would compel someone to try out that substitution? What advantage does it offer (aside from making the problem EPLS)?

Comment: "EPLS" hahahaha +1

Comment: @user170231 The obvious fact: $\cosh t\pm\sinh t=e^{\pm t}$

Comment: @user170231 I can't speak for Anastasiya's brother, but in my own experience, most unintuitive ('magical') substitutions are just a retrospective shorthand, and were initially a very intuitive *chain* of substitutions.

Comment: @TheCount Why on earth did you put the bound in my answer since $K$ must be in the form of $n$??

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 Oh my goodness you're right. I'm so sorry. Moment of silliness! Will revert.

Comment: (+1) Cool as usual!! :-) Although there's nothing *weirdo* about the sub (successive $x = \arcsin y$ and $z = \frac{1-y}{1+y}$ subs work too!) :-)

Comment: @user170231  what's epls?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD A new classification of integrals coined by the OP :)